# How to load specific packages from a server with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that I am writing to extract all the jobs of a specific server like

```
$sqlserver = "Servername"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo') | Out-Null

$srv = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $sqlserver

$jobs = $srv.JobServer.Jobs

ForEach ($job in $jobs)
  {
   $jobname =$Servernaam.replace("\","_") + '_'+ $job.Name.replace(" ","_").replace("\","_").replace("[","_").replace("]","_").replace(".","_").replace(":","_") + ".sql"
   $job.Script() | Out-File C:\Users\Desktop\Jobs_from_Server\Orgineel\$jobname
    if ($jobs -like '*.dtsx*')
  }
```

The code I got now gets all the jobs from the server and store them in separate files.

The problem is that I only want to get the jobs of the Micrososft SQL Server that contains **.dtsx** in the string of **@command**

I tried for example

```
ForEach ($job in $jobs)
  {
   $jobname =$Servernaam.replace("\","_") + '_'+ $job.Name.replace(" ","_").replace("\","_").replace("[","_").replace("]","_").replace(".","_").replace(":","_") + ".sql"
   $job.Script() | Out-File C:\Users\Desktop\Jobs_from_Server\Orgineel\$jobname

    if ($jobs -like '*.dtsx*')
```

I also have tried  `- Contain` and set the code in the foreachloop like

```
ForEach ($job in $jobs |if ($jobs -like '*.dtsx*'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a number of typos and other errors in which objects you're using where. Try this as a starter. It assumes that the first step in a job that uses SSIS is an SSIS step. Modify as needed.

The key here is checking the `subsystem` of the job step(s) to detect if the step is run with the SSIS subsystem.

```
$sqlserver = "servername"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo') | Out-Null

$srv = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $sqlserver

$jobs = $srv.JobServer.Jobs

ForEach ($job in $jobs)
  {
    if ($Job.JobSteps[0].Subsystem -eq "ssis") {
        # Do SSIS stuff
        write-output "Found an SSIS job $($job.name)"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nice code gets accectly the jobs i need. You where also right about the typos so i have begun form scratch with your code as the basis